# i915 frame buffer console cannot be set to 800x600? (Lubuntu 14.04)

Tags: display-resolution, console, i915, kms

I have an Intel Atom (N525, Cedarview) based mainboard which I'm trying to use with Ubuntu (Lubuntu, to be exact, but the problem should exist in the normal version as well). I use the kernel drm and fbcon modules together with the i915 kernel driver, plus the intel xserver from xorg. I'm using the stock versions of the kernel, xorg etc.

X11 runs fine, I could get it to run 800x600 (the board is connected via VGA to an older 10-inch 800x600 touch panel) by using xrandr to add the necessary mode.

The text consoles, however don't seem to work properly. As soon as I load the i915 module, the screen switched to 1024x768 (which results in barely legible text on the 800x600 screen). I have tried to manually reset the display to 800x600 using fbset, but that doesn't work either - the resolution stays the same, it just uses less of the screen. Only the upper left corner is used, the rest of the screen still holds the remnants of the text printed before switching and the "clear" command only clears that upper left area. I look like a (borderless) windows overlays the previous output (I can prived a screenshot if necessary).

How can I get the i915 driver and the rest of the system to properly display 800x600 text consoles? Can anybody give me any pointer what to try next? Any help is appreciated!

Cheers, Michael.

Comment: I had luck by adding these options to the linux boot line: i915.modeset=1 video=1920x1080